# How can i do this with a stack? VB

Tags: vb.net, stack, items

My problem will be in pseudo code below:

I Want to push stackA into stackTemp automatically until stackTemp.Peek= TextBox Value.

Then Pop that value and add all items in stackTemp into a list box, and also back into Stack A.

```
Begin
    stackA <- 1122
    stackA <- 1234
    stackA <- 2273

    btnSearch.Click:
    stackTemp.Push(stackA.Push)
    stringSearch <- stackTemp.Peek

    If stringSearch = stackTemp.Peek then
        ListBox1.Items.Add( **All Items In stackTemp** )
        stackA.Push( **All Items in stackTemp** )
    Else
        **Keep Poppping stackA into stackTemp until above happens**
    End If
End
```

If anybody has any help for me that would be great!!!!!

**Addition:**
My code so far is below:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

    stackTemp.Push(stackA.Pop)
    stringSearch = stackTemp.Peek
    If stringSearch = TextBox1.Text then
        stackTemp.Pop()


        For Each item As String In stackTemp
            Listbox1.items.add(item)
        Next
    Else
        'Do Nothing
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  It appears that you want all the values in stackA that are less than or equal to the value in TextBox1.  Is it any more complicated than that?